# Passing in an Integer with select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this is in my controller

```
def index
    @tutor = Tutor.where(:admin => false)
    @tutor = @tutor.subject_search(params[:subject_search]) if params[:subject_search].present? 
    @tutor = @tutor.fees_search(params[:fees_search]) if params[:fees_search].present?
end
```

And this are the methods from the model

The `fees_search` method

```
def self.fees_search(amount)
    @tutor ||= Tutor.where(admin: false)
    @tutor.map do |tutor|
      @fees = tutor.profile.fees
      if @fees <= amount
        #puts 'if is working'
        @tutor = tutor
      else
        #puts 'else is working'
        @tutor = nil
      end
      @tutor
    end
  end
```

And this is the `subject_search` method

```
def self.subject_search(name)
    @result = Subject.where("name LIKE ?" , "#{name}").take
    @tutor = @result.tutors
  end
```

So i can do something like `@tutor = Tutor.subject_search('English')` in my rails console followed by `@tutor.fees_search(20)` and i get a result.

However when done in my index view, i receive the error `comparison of Fixnum with String failed`

So based on the views in the form

```
<%= label_tag 'fees_search', 'Fees' %>
<%= select_tag 'fees_search', options_from_collection_for_select(, :selected => params[:fees_search]), :include_blank => true, class:'form-control' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Filter', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
```

And when i inspect in the browser, i see `<option value = "10">` (and so on and so forth) which im guessing is the reason the error is coming out? If thats the case how can i set my `select_tag` to output `integer` values instead?

Or is there a more elegant solution for filtering for subjects and/or fees? Is there a need for me to post the relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Params values will always be string you need to convert the param value to integer using `to_i`

```
@tutor = 
  @tutor.fees_search(params[:fees_search].to_i) if params[:fees_search].present?
```

or you can convert it to integer in the method itself.

```
if @fees <= amount.to_i # This is where actually you are getting the error
  @tutor = tutor
else
  @tutor = nil
end
```

This will give you expected result.